How to upload a file xml with NodeJS v18 to a SharePoint Online?
I shouaite upload a file . xml in a folder of an online sharepoint, I only have the client_id the client_secret and the url of my sharepoint. Unfortunately, I can’t find a solution.sharepointnodejsxmlfrench
I tried to do it with pnp but the version is not compatible with nodejs 18 and I can’t do it with versions 3 & 4. I can’t find other methods or libraries that will allow me to do it.I want to upload my file to my sharepoint folder. Currently there is nothing that works
